# Looking for Bernoulli Equation that would describe how a hair drier, pointed nozzle up, could keep a ping pong ball suspended in mid-air

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to find a specific equation from Bernoulli and the type of math required to work with/explain it. It's from fluid dynamics. The fluid is air and the equation(s) would describe how a hair drier, pointed nozzle up, could keep a ping pong ball suspended in mid-air.

Bernoulli wrote a lot of great stuff, however, since I lack an engineering background, I believe I have found only equations (and other work) that are not applicable.

Does someone recall the name of this equation and the type of math required to solve it?

Comment: The equation that describes fluid flow in general is Navier-Stokes equation. This is a partial differential equation - hard to solve in general. In your case there may be some simplifications to be done.

Comment: The phenomenon you are describing is called the [Coanda effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect).